# Morphia with play - very ugly issue

Tags: playframework, morphia

I've installed Morphia 1.2.4b and I have play 1.2.3.

I want to access default page but I receive this error:

```
    Oops: NoSuchMethodError
An unexpected error occured caused by exception NoSuchMethodError: com.mongodb.WriteConcern.valueOf(Ljava/lang/String;)Lcom/mongodb/WriteConcern;

play.exceptions.UnexpectedException: Unexpected Error
    at play.Invoker$Invocation.onException(Invoker.java:232)
    at play.Invoker$Invocation.run(Invoker.java:273)
    at Invocation.HTTP Request(Play!)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.mongodb.WriteConcern.valueOf(Ljava/lang/String;)Lcom/mongodb/WriteConcern;
    at play.modules.morphia.MorphiaPlugin.configureDs_(MorphiaPlugin.java:574)
    at play.modules.morphia.MorphiaPlugin.onApplicationStart(MorphiaPlugin.java:453)
    at play.plugins.PluginCollection.onApplicationStart(PluginCollection.java:425)
    at play.Play.start(Play.java:495)
    at play.Play.detectChanges(Play.java:599)
    at play.Invoker$Invocation.init(Invoker.java:186)
    ... 1 more
```

I already lost 2 hours with this and I don't find any work-around.

Can you guys give me a clue?

Answer (score 0):

Issue solved:

- I was using **mongo** module in the same application, together with **morphia** module. Even if I uninstalled it, the issue still persisted. After making a new project from scratch only with morphia, things are back to normal.